# Вывод элементов списка в нужном формате

Tags: python, list

Написал небольшой конвертор hex2dec

```
input_mac = input("МАС : ")
mac_list = list(input_mac)
if len(mac_list) == 17 :
    mac = [j for i, j in enumerate(mac_list) if i not in [2,5,8,11,14]] # зафильтровываем двоеточия/тире
print('Конвертируем ' + str(len(mac)) + ' символов!')
length = len(mac) - 1
symbol_a = 0
symbol_b = 1
dec_mac = []
while symbol_a <= length: # конвертируем hex2dec
    x = mac[symbol_a] + mac[symbol_b]
    x = int(x, 16)
    dec_mac.append(str(x))
    symbol_a += 2
    symbol_b += 2
print(dec_mac[0] + '.' + dec_mac[1] + '.' + dec_mac[2] + '.' + dec_mac[3] + '.' + dec_mac[4] + '.' + dec_mac[5])
```

Собственно последний кусок получился громоздким, можно ли как то упростить его?

```
print(dec_mac[0] + '.' + dec_mac[1] + '.' + dec_mac[2] + '.' + dec_mac[3] + '.' + dec_mac[4] + '.' + dec_mac[5])
```

Comment: `print(".".join(dec_mac))` ?

Comment: или можно вместо ``dec_mac.append(str(x))`` сразу строить нужную строку

Comment: @MaxU спасибо. Функция join прекрасно решила проблему.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй fstring, вот пример.

```
>>> name = "Eric"
>>> age = 74
>>> f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
'Hello, Eric. You are 74.'
```